# jquery popup closes immediately after opening in cordova iOS 9

Tags: jquery, cordova, popup, ios9

I have this popup that is created in a function in cordova.

```
var problem_list2 = new Array();
function addSymptom(symptom){
    $.ajaxSetup({   async: false});
    //$.mobile.loading('show');
    if($.inArray(symptom, problem_list2)===-1){ 
        problem_list2.push(symptom);
        //var lis = problem_list2;
        var $popUp = $("<div/>").popup({
            dismissible : true,
            theme : "a",
            overlayTheme : "a",
            transition : "slide"
        }).bind("popupafterclose", function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $("<h2/>", {
            text : "Problem List"
        }).appendTo($popUp);
        for(var i=0;i<problem_list2.length;i++){
            $("<h4/>", {          
                text : problem_list2[i]
           }).appendTo($popUp);
        }
        $('<input type="button" data-iconpos="right" data-icon="plus" value="Add More Symptoms" onclick="closer()">').appendTo($popUp);
        $('<input type="button" data-iconpos="right" data-icon="check" value="Diagnose" onclick="diagnose()">').appendTo($popUp);          
        $popUp.popup("open").trigger("create");                   
    }
}
```

When the close button is pressed, this function closes the popup:

```
function closer(){    
    $('.ui-popup').popup('close'); 
}
```

It works fine in any web browser and cordova android. But in cordova iOS 9 the popup immediately closes when its opened the first time. After the first time it stays open and this behavior only occurs the first time it opens. I tried adding data-history='false' this way:

```
var problem_list2 = new Array();
function addSymptom(symptom){
    $.ajaxSetup({   async: false});
    //$.mobile.loading('show');
    if($.inArray(symptom, problem_list2)===-1){ 
        problem_list2.push(symptom);
        //var lis = problem_list2;
        var $popUp = $("<div data-history='false' />").popup({
            dismissible : true,
            theme : "a",
            overlayTheme : "a",
            transition : "slide"
        }).bind("popupafterclose", function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $("<h2/>", {
            text : "Problem List"
        }).appendTo($popUp);
        for(var i=0;i<problem_list2.length;i++){
            $("<h4/>", {          
                text : problem_list2[i]
           }).appendTo($popUp);
        }
        $('<input type="button" data-iconpos="right" data-icon="plus" value="Add More Symptoms" onclick="closer()">').appendTo($popUp);
        $('<input type="button" data-iconpos="right" data-icon="check" value="Diagnose" onclick="diagnose()">').appendTo($popUp);          
        $popUp.popup("open").trigger("create");                   
    }
}
```

and this way:

```
var problem_list2 = new Array();
function addSymptom(symptom){
    $.ajaxSetup({   async: false});
    //$.mobile.loading('show');
    if($.inArray(symptom, problem_list2)===-1){ 
        problem_list2.push(symptom);
        //var lis = problem_list2;
        var $popUp = $("<div/>").popup({
            dismissible : true,
            datahistory : 'false',
            theme : "a",
            overlayTheme : "a",
            transition : "slide"
        }).bind("popupafterclose", function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $("<h2/>", {
            text : "Problem List"
        }).appendTo($popUp);
        for(var i=0;i<problem_list2.length;i++){
            $("<h4/>", {          
                text : problem_list2[i]
           }).appendTo($popUp);
        }
        $('<input type="button" data-iconpos="right" data-icon="plus" value="Add More Symptoms" onclick="closer()">').appendTo($popUp);
        $('<input type="button" data-iconpos="right" data-icon="check" value="Diagnose" onclick="diagnose()">').appendTo($popUp);          
        $popUp.popup("open").trigger("create");                   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put data-history="false" on your popup div